# Servlet Session in RAP Workbench advisor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rap

I am adding an attribute in a servlet session using following code

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
  throws ServletException, IOException 
{
  req.getSession().setAttribute("USER",userObject);
}
```

and I am trying to access it in RAP `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` class `postWindowOpen` method like following

```java
RWT.getRequest().getSession().getAttribute("USER")
```

above scenario is not working after I migrate to RAP version 3.0. in RAP 2.0 it was working fine.

As I debug the application i could see the session attribute in HashMap but it is not accessible through getAttribute function, please view the image bellow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAjYU.png)

Comment: How is the Servlet that sets the attribute registered? And how is the RAP servlet registered? Did you examine the session to see if it is actually the same? I guess you are having two different sessions here.

Comment: Servlet is register through org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets extension. and i am accessing it in workbenchwindowadvisor class this was working fine in RAP 2

Answer (score 1):

This is likely not a change in RAP itself, but in Equinox. I suppose your servlet is now considered part of another "web application", and thus gets a different `ServletContext`. Since `HttpSession` is scoped to the `ServletContext`, you'll end up with different `HttpSession`s. There have been changes in this regard to Equinox meanwhile (see for example [this discussion](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=390381)).

To verify this theory, you could try to run RAP 3 with an older version of Equinox.

As a workaround, you may consider using a [ServiceHandler](https://www.eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=resources.html&version=3.0) instead of a servlet, or register your servlet programmatically in the context of the RAP application.

**Update:**
It seems that this issue can be resolved in RAP 3.1, see [bug 480326](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480326).

Comment: Older Equinox version have some dependency issues, because equinox servlet older version not working with equinox.jetty new version and when i replaced the equinox.jetty older version it's conflicting with jetty server version because its dependency is set on jetty version till 9 and RAP3 comes with jetty version 9.2.9.. here is the question can RAP3 work with jetty version 9?. i can not use the ServiceHandler because i need to run the servlet before workbench initialization

Comment: Or can i use different-app servlet context inside the rap servlet context?

Comment: Thank you ralfstx **ServiceHandler** work for me in this scenario. Thanks again

Comment: Can you please let me know the httpcontextid of RAP workbench so I can use it in equinox servlet.

Comment: @ArifSorathia https://github.com/eclipse/rap/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.rap.ui.workbench/Eclipse%20UI/org/eclipse/rap/ui/internal/servlet/HttpServiceTracker.java#L30

Comment: It seems that this issue can be resolved in RAP 3.1, see bug 480326.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently created a Bugzilla issue for this problem:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480326

Regards,
Ivan

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I was thinking that there might be some other context id for accessing RWT servlet context, but i was wrong..